# Why aren't duplicates deleted?

Tags: discussion, deletion, exact-duplicates

Let's say a question is closed as duplicate and someone provided the link of the original question: 
 
*Wouldn't it be better that duplicates are deleted off of the site? Or deleting them would be a waste of time and generally does no improvement to the site?* 
I have no idea whether deleting duplicates permanently does technical improvements to the website.. So if anyone can help regarding this issue, it would be much appreciated. 
Also, if there's no significant improvement resulting from the permanent deletion, then it is definitely a waste of time.

Comment: Many closed duplicates are useful to funnel duplicate traffic to the main duplicate because of their variations in titles and statements.  In some cases a duplicate does not even add this value, and is fair game to delete.

Comment: A related older discussion: [Is it okay to delete unanswered, marked as duplicates questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22181) It was pointed out there (and in the above comment) that duplicates actually [can be useful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9586/avoiding-duplicates/9588#9588) in some cases.

Comment: Some of them, when they are PSQs, should be deleted, and should have been closed as not fit for this site due to lacking context.  But some dupes are very well asked questions, and, as @rschwieb argues, can help to funnel duplicate traffic to the main traffic.  But I think PSQ dupes serve no purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. It is fair to say that everyone has his own way of expressing his/ her question.

Comment: Duplicates seem to shield poor posts from being deleted, as well as bounties apparently do. This is not good. If there are good reasons to delete a question, it should be possible under all circumstances.

Comment: @Peter Can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: I often wanted to vote to delete already closed and downvoted questions , but could not because of a duplicate or a bounty.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that was one of the reasons that made me ask this very question. Some duplicates are better off deleted in my opinion. But, then again, moderators certainly know what they are doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a combination of the comments mentioned by the kind users:

- Everyone has their own way of expressing their problem/ question.
- Closing duplicates instead of deleting them helps in funneling the duplicates and redirecting those who asked the original question hence building up a series of duplicates leading to the main question.
- This answer by a moderator proves to be helpful as well: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22183/784761

Comment: I find it somewhat ironic that the sentence reading "Everyone has his own way of expressing his problem/question" (which was the particular expression of the original author) was edited to change the pronouns (thus depriving that author of their original expression).  While I have sympathy for making attempts to make the language here more gender-neutral, (1) editing a post *just* to change the pronouns isn't really appropriate, and (2) in this case, I think that it is doubly inappropriate, as the answer author is also the question author, and the "his" appears to be self-referential. :/